# Cell shaded effect

Tags: shaders, color, shadows

Is it possible to get a cell shaded effect on blender similar to the image below? 
http://gamegrass.com/game_img/2013/02/01/754.jpg

Comment: What you're looking for is FREESTYLE RENDERING ENGINE in Blender (https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/FreeStyle).